# Delete element from list-group by clicking it

Tags: javascript, html, mysql, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

So, I made a bootstrap group-list to list the messages from  mysql 'email' table. When an email is new the box is blue and when i click it, it becomes grey[This is the group-list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/avfJn.png)

So now, i want to click a box which is unread and become read. And here comes the problem: Despite which box will I click, only the first one will be marked as read. I think that "this" keeps the elements of the first object of the list. So, how can I choose which message will be marked as read? 
This is EmailsReader.java doGet method:

```
    String rec=(String)session.getAttribute("uname");
            ps =con.prepareStatement("select * from email where receiver=? and new=1");
            ps.setString(1, rec);
            rs =ps.executeQuery();

            ps2 =con.prepareStatement("select * from email where receiver=? and new=0");
            ps2.setString(1, rec);
            rs2 =ps2.executeQuery();

            result = "";
            boolean flag1 = rs.next();
            boolean flag2= rs2.next();
            if(!flag1 && !flag2){
                result += "<div class='alert-float' style='position: absolute; top: 0; left: 130px; right: 30px; z-index: 9999;width: 65%'>"
                        +"<div class='alert alert-warning' role='alert'>"  
                        +" <button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert'>x</button>"  
                        +"<strong>Ohh nooo!</strong> Try not to feel lonely cause you have no emails.. :("
                        +"</div>"
                        +"</div>";
            }
            else{
                result += "<div class='list-group' id='emailList'>";
                while (flag1) {             //list of unread email

                    sender=rs.getString("sender");
                    theme=rs.getString("theme");
                    message=rs.getString("message");
                    result += "<a href='#' class='list-group-item list-group-item-action active' onclick='makeInactive(this)'>"
                            + "<h5 id='send' class='list-group-item-heading'>" + sender+ "</h5>"
                            + "<button id='trash' type='submit' onclick='deleteEmail(this)'>"
                            + "<span id='trash' class='glyphicon glyphicon-trash'></span>"
                            + "</button>";
                    result += "<h6 id='th' class='list-group-item-heading'>" + theme+ "</h6>" 
                            + "<p id='msg' class='list-group-item-text'>" + message+ "</p>"
                            + "</a>";

                    flag1 = rs.next();
                }

                while (flag2) {            //list of read email

                    result += "<a href='#' class='list-group-item list-group-item-action'>"
                            + "<h5 id='send' class='list-group-item-heading'>" + rs2.getString("sender")+ "</h5>"
                            + "<button id='trash' type='submit' onclick='deleteEmail(this)'>"
                            + "<span id='trash' class='glyphicon glyphicon-trash'></span>"
                            + "</button>";
                    result += "<h6 id='th' class='list-group-item-heading'>" + rs2.getString("theme")+ "</h6>" 
                            + "<p id='msg' class='list-group-item-text'>" + rs2.getString("message")+ "</p>"
                            + "</a>";

                    flag2 = rs2.next();
                }
                result += "</div>";

            }
        }
```

This ie EmailReader.java doPost Method:

```
String sender = request.getParameter("sender");
    String theme = request.getParameter("theme");
    String message = request.getParameter("message");

     Connection con=null;   
     try{

        con=DBConnection.getCon();
        PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("update email set new=0 where sender=? AND theme=? AND message=?"); 
        ps.setString(1, sender);
        ps.setString(2, theme);
        ps.setString(3, message);
        ps.executeUpdate();     

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Javascript and ajax code

```
    var j = jQuery.noConflict();
function emailRead() {
j.ajax({
    type : 'GET',
    url : '../emailReader',
    success : function(data) {
        j("#emailList").html(data);
    }
}); 
}emailRead();
function makeInactive(attr) {
var sender = document.getElementById("send").innerHTML;
var theme = document.getElementById("th").innerHTML;
var message = document.getElementById("msg").innerHTML;
j.ajax({
    type : 'POST',
    url : '../emailReader',
    data : {
        "sender" : sender,
        "theme" : theme,
        "message" : message
    },
    success : function(data) {
        j.ajax({
            type : 'GET',
            url : '../emailReader',
            success : function(data) {
                j("#emailList").html(data);
            }
        });
    }
});
}
```

So, the function I want to fix is the makeInactive(this).I understand that the problem is in the making of the box. How can i fix this?